# How to replace date pattern in javascript string

Tags: javascript, string

How to remove a date patterns in a JavaScript string like below?
from "Mobile Phone 1/15/06" to "Mobile Phone"

```
var str ="Mobile Phone 1/15/06";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** You could use regex to match and replace the date pattern:

```js
var str ="Mobile Phone 1/15/06";
var result = str.replace(/\s+\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}/g, '');
document.write(result);
```

Comment: Small change to your code to support "1/1/06"
str2.replace(/\s+\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}/g, '');

Comment: Updated the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `substring()` method. You can find more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

It would look like this.

```
var str = "Mobile Phone 1/15/16"
var sub = str.substring(0,12)
```